# Transform or change values of columns in based on values of others columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains 5 columns. What I would like to do is to change the last 4 columns to the first column.

Basically if the value of the first column is below a certain threshold, the following columns are modified and if this value is higher than the threshold there is no change.

So I tried this :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'col1' : [0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2],
  'col2' : [2,4,3,7],
  'col3' : [3,4,4,9],
  'col4' : [4,2,2,6],
  'col5' : [0.3, 2.1, 1.0, .9],
})

def motif(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5):
  col2 = col2
  col3 = col3
  col4 = col4
  col5 = col5
  if col1 <=.15:
    col2 = col2 * .15
    col3 = col3 * .15
    col4 = col4 * .15
    col5 = col5 * .15
    return col2, col3, col4, col5
  else:
    return col2, col3, col4, col5

df.apply(lambda x: modify(x[col1], x[col2], x[col3], x[col4], x[col5]), axis=1)
```

But this does not work.
If you have any ideas I would be very grateful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to select rows where `col1` is less than or equal to `.15` then multiply the rest of the columns by `.15`:

```
df.loc[df['col1'] <= 0.15, 'col2':] *= 0.15
```

`df`:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4   col5
0   0.1  0.30  0.45   0.6  0.045
1   0.3  4.00  4.00   2.0  2.100
2   0.1  0.45  0.60   0.3  0.150
3   0.2  7.00  9.00   6.0  0.900
```

---

Naturally other column selections work if all columns after `col2` is overly broad:

```
df.loc[df['col1'] <= 0.15, ['col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']] *= 0.15
```

```
df.loc[df['col1'] <= 0.15, 'col2':'col5'] *= 0.15
```

---

The mask can also be saved and reused if different columns need different modifications:

```
m = df['col1'] <= 0.15
df.loc[m, 'col2':'col4'] *= 0.15
df.loc[m, 'col5'] *= 0.5  # col5 is different than col2-4
```

`df`:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0   0.1  0.30  0.45   0.6  0.15
1   0.3  4.00  4.00   2.0  2.10
2   0.1  0.45  0.60   0.3  0.50
3   0.2  7.00  9.00   6.0  0.90
```

---

The [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) can work (although it is slower and a *lot* more code), but since `apply` can produce both aggregated and unaggregated results the overwritten columns will need explicitly defined and the result needs to be a `Series` not a `tuple`:

```
def modify(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5):
    if col1 <= .15:
        col2 = col2 * .15
        col3 = col3 * .15
        col4 = col4 * .15
        col5 = col5 * .15
    return pd.Series([col2, col3, col4, col5])


df[['col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']] = df.apply(lambda x: modify(
    x['col1'], x['col2'], x['col3'], x['col4'], x['col5']
), axis=1)
```

`df`:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4   col5
0   0.1  0.30  0.45   0.6  0.045
1   0.3  4.00  4.00   2.0  2.100
2   0.1  0.45  0.60   0.3  0.150
3   0.2  7.00  9.00   6.0  0.900
```